# Kotlin - running ksoap2 as a coroutine vs async - which is better?

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, android-ksoap2

Android and Kotlin noob here - I have an app calling a SOAP web service. Right now the calls are made using Thread and communication is working. I would like to move that to either Kotlin coroutines or Android Async tasks, my question is - which is better in this case?

I've tried creating a coroutine call based on this article
https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-make-sense-of-kotlin-coroutines-b666c7151b93, basically adapting this pattern:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val deferredResult = async {
        delay(1000L)
        "World!"
    }
    println("Hello, ${deferredResult.await()}")
}
```

When I put the web service call in the coroutine async, then Android Studio highlights the HttpTransportSE call method (http://www.kobjects.org/ksoap2/doc/api/org/ksoap2/transport/HttpTransportSE.html) with the following warning:

*Inappropriate blocking method call. Reports thread-blocking method calls found in a code fragment where a thread should not be blocked"*

My understanding of this message is that the call made by the HttpTransportSE blocks the thread, therefore we lose the advantage of using coroutines, and I should just stick to the Async task.
Is that interpretation correct, or is there a way of wrapping the call with coroutine that would work more properly?

Below is my code (it communicates with the web services, but because of the warning I have a feeling it's not a proper way to do this):

```
fun callWebService(
...
): String {
    val defferedResult: Deferred<String> = GlobalScope.async {
        try {
...
            val envelope = SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12)
...
            val androidHttpTransport = HttpTransportSE(URL)
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true
            androidHttpTransport.call("$NAMESPACE/$methodName", envelope)    //this is where I get the warning
            val resultData = envelope.response
            webResponse = "$resultData"
...
        }
        return@async webResponse
    }
    return runBlocking { defferedResult.await() }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured it out, thanks to this [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-i-getting-the-background-3e0e54d20bb)
it comes down to running in the background using`Dispatchers.IO`
the SOAP call can be regular function, no need for Deffered, etc.

I am using MVVM model with repository, so all the background work is happening on the `Repository` level, triggered by button press in the `Fragment` launched in the respective `ViewModel`, with limited scope

my SOAP call now looks like this

```
fun callWebService(...): String {
        try {
...
            val envelope = SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12)
...
            val androidHttpTransport = HttpTransportSE(URL)
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true
            androidHttpTransport.call("$NAMESPACE/$methodName", envelope)    
            val resultData = envelope.response
            webResponse = "$resultData"
...
        }
        return webResponse
}
```

in the `Repository` I have following function - note the `suspend` and `Dispatchers.IO`

```
    suspend fun insertAndSend(task: Task) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = callWebService(processedTask)
            processedTask.status = response
            taskDao.update(processedTask)
        }
    }
```

in the `ViewModel` I call the `Repository` function within the `ViewModelScope`

```
//defined in ViewModel class
 fun insertAndSend(task: Task) = viewModelScope.launch { repository.insertAndSend(task) }
```

which is triggered in the respective `Fragment` by pressing a button